# Highcharts multiple splines on same axis and independent from each other

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have found in highcharts, that all series data is relative to one another. I have two splines that need to be on the same axis as some stacked columns because they all share the same data and need to be shown at the same scale.

If a user hides one of the splines, the other spline then moves and shows the incorrect data.

Is it possible to have a two axis chart that where both axis have the same scale, or even better to display the two splines on the same axis as the columns but for the splines not be stacked?

Comment: "the other spline then moves and shows the incorrect data" -- what do you mean? How does it move incorrectly? Sounds like you just want a static `min` and `max` for your x-axis...?

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo, meantime you can check how use the multiple axis in [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)